# Possible Nvidia Geforce 755m driver problem - Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, screen, 14.10

I have noticed lately that my screen has gone black for a couple seconds, then went back to normal.  This will happen regardless of the application I am in, and in a bad spell will occur every 30 seconds or so.  Through some research and suggestions from friends, I have tried to diagnose this as a driver issue.  I have an Nvidia GeForce 755m graphics card, which works fine with my Windows 8.1 configuration.  I have tried to download the proper drivers for my graphics card and there is always an error when I run the file. Here is the link for the driver I tried to download: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/78469/en-us

Is Nvidia supported in linux? Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: does it completely go black or does it go to a dark greyish translucent color and back to normal?

Comment: Completely black.  This is different from the usual screen timeout thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nVidia Geforce 755m is a mobile chipset with [nVidia Optimus technology](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html). It is very well supported in Ubuntu.

I have had some issues using the generic [Nouveau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouveau_%28software%29) drivers. I faced similar issues as you(i used to get black screen and that used to log me out forcefully. I would then login and just pray to install the nvidia drivers before the blackout occurs again. I was too naive to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> and install the drivers from the terminal). So i installed the Nvidia proprietary drivers from Ubuntu Repository and that resolved the black screen issues.

Instead of downloading drivers from nvidia website you can do what i did. If you are on unity, go to unity dash and search for `additional drivers`. This will then list out the supported drivers for your card. You can then activate the proprietary and tested nvidia drivers. This should resolve your issue.

This would install a nVidia control panel from where you can switch between nVidia or intel chipset for graphics processing. There is also an ongoing [Bumblebee Project](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/is-a-nvidia-geforce-with-optimus-technology-supported-by-ubuntu) which will allow you to dynamically switch between the chipsets. But this is a bit advanced tech for me. So i will leave it upto you to decide if you want to try out bumblebee or simply install the proprietary nVidia drivers.

Comment: Worked perfectly, I was using Nouveau drivers and switched to nvidia, everything works great now.  Thank you!